# class="hidden sm:flex" doesn't work in TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to make my navbar responsive by adding hidden sm:flex to a specific item. Meaning it'll hidden by default but show only on small screens and above. I made some debug and discover that hidden override everything even the responsive variants. Other display properties work will on responsive variants. here's my code:

```
className="hidden sm:flex sm:w-2/5 w-11/12 mt-4 sm:mt-0 items-center shadow-md"
```

Answer (score 5):

Tailwind is driven by mobile first design, just like bootstrap and some other CSS frameworks. Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design/#mobile-first

That means that classes without variants will be applied to smaller screens first, and then you can add variants for bigger screens.

So, the thing that you want to achieve should be like this:

```html
className="flex md:hidden w-2/5 md:w-11/12 mt-0 md:mt-4 items-center shadow-md"
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for help, but I want it to be hidden in small screens and visible in bigger screens

Comment: Then your question is not clearly asked.

To achieve that, you will need to do this `hidden md:flex` - that will hide it on smaller screens and will show it on bigger screens.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: `hidden md:flex md:visible` solved my issue - Thanks @ben

Comment: Is there a recommended way to only apply classes in the small state?

Comment: @SethWhite you can put all of your classes that are for `sm` state first, and then with `md` selector do the opposite of what is `sm` behavior. 

For example, if you want color of text to be white on small screens, but black on all other screens you do something like `text-white md:text-black` and that's it!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error in a rails application. The issue was that I was importing tailwind base styles twice. Check the code below.

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "tailwindcss/screens";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind screens;
```

To fix make sure you only import them once like this:

```
 @import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "tailwindcss/screens";
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the guide I followed only advised me to import the following:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The solution for me was simple. I added the following import:

```
@tailwind screens;
```

Background: svelte^3.0.0 with tailwind^3.0.24

Answer (score 2):

Might be probably too late but for someone looking for an answer the  solution is to remove

```
@tailwind screens;
```