# TailwindCss's mobile breakpoints do not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, tailwind-css

I am building a custom navbar in Gatsby using TailwindCss for styling. For reference I am following a tutorial on YouTube which's code can be found [here](https://codepen.io/chris__sev/pen/QWGjQKe?editors=1000).

When I use the mobile breakpoints as prefix like in the example below only the div saying "mobile" works as it should be:

**Layout.js**

```
<nav>
  <div className={"flex"}>
    <div className={"hidden md:flex"}>desktop</div>
    <div className={"md:hidden"}>mobile</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

**styles/global.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind screens;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The output "desktop" should be shown when the text "mobile" vanishes but for some reason it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with Tailwind?

[image]

**EDIT:** Reproduction example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-tailwind-pr3kd)

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qope2x5n/. You probably need to share a [mcve] so we can have a look what could've gone wrong. It's difficult to share React MCVE as a stack snippet, but you can always host an example of codesandbox.io

Comment: I've added a Codesandbox example project

Comment: I am not the most well-verse with tailwind, but It seems like "hidden" is a powerful class that kinda overshadow other display settings. From this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041899/class-hidden-smflex-doesnt-work-in-tailwindcss, I believe you may need to try `{"hidden md:visible md:flex"} desktop`

Comment: Wasn't the problem but thanks for your helpfulness :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in your `global.css` file.

You should not add the `@tailwind screens;`. Since you are using the latest TailwindCSS, `@tailwind screens;` was deprecated since 2.2 in JIT mode and it's now named: `@tailwind variants;`

[Tailwind Changelog](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases?q=%40tailwind%20screens%3B&expanded=true#deprecate-tailwind-screens-for-tailwind-variants-in-just-in-time-mode)

> As of v2.2, the @tailwind screens directive has been renamed to
> @tailwind variants, since it is now the injection point for all
> variants, not just responsive variants.

Some more info on when the `@tailwind variants;` should be added:

> The @tailwind variants feature is considered an advanced escape hatch
> and we recommend omitting it by default. You should only use it if
> your project won't work properly without it, which is only ever really
> true if you are introducing Tailwind to a legacy system with a very
> fragile existing CSS codebase that has styles that absolutely need to
> be at the very end of the stylesheet for things to work.

Also, according to the [Tailwind installation with Gatsby instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby) You should not add the `@tailwind variants;`

That being said, you should not need it in this case so, by just removing it in you `global.css` file will fix the issue.

Your new global.css file should be:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

[Here is a working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-tailwind-forked-w7lkp?file=/src/styles/global.css)

Comment: The order of the `@tailwind` directive being used in the CSS also matters: it has to be in the order of base > components > utilities > variants: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved after I have noticed that the autoprefixer plugin was missing in the `postcss.config.js`. Just redid the [installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/gatsby) for Gatsby.